# escaping hash (#) in cron

Tags: cron, escaping

The following line works in cron:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/mosquitto_pub -h  test.mosquitto.org -p 1883 -u dragino -t /MyExample/Topic -m "GPING-GPING-4-GPING-GPING"
```

This one doesn´t:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/mosquitto_pub -h  test.mosquitto.org -p 1883 -u dragino -t /MyExample/Topic -m "GPING#GPING#4#GPING#GPING"
```

Notice I changed the `-` characters to `#` inside the message. I understand that the `#` character needs scaping, but how? `\#` didn't work.

Comment: which cron are you using?

Comment: it´s the cron used in Dragino products (Arduino Yun based, OpenWRT). Do you want me to check some specific version? If so, how can I check it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Escape all # with \, as # denotes a comment in bash-scripts such as cron runs.
`\#` should allow the script to run.

Comment: As I said "\#" didn´t work, but thanks for your idea.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is incorrect:

> Blank lines, leading spaces, and tabs are ignored.  Lines whose first non-white space character is a <pound-sign> (`#`) are comments and are not processed.  **Note that comments are not allowed on the same line as cron commands since they are considered a part of the command.**  Similarly, comments are not allowed on the same line as environment variable settings.
>
> **<sub>source: `man 5 crontab`</sub>**

You can easily test this with:

```
* * * * * echo "#" > ~/foo.txt
```

Your issue is most likely related to `mosquitto_pub`. Although unversed in the topic, it seems that you can only have a single `#` in your message and it should be at the end.

An alternative solution could be to create a script `/path/to/run_cronscript.sh` which contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

/usr/bin/mosquitto_pub -h  test.mosquitto.org -p 1883 -u dragino -t /MyExample/Topic -m "GPING#GPING#4#GPING#GPING"
```

and adjust your crontab as:

```
* * * * * /path/to/run_cronscript.sh
```

Comment: You can only have 1 `#` in the topic and it must be at the end, you can have as many `#` as you want in the message payload

Comment: If I use the command with the "#" directly from command line it works OK. Just inside cron it doesn´t work. But thanks for your input.

Comment: @DanielFernandes What you could do is to write your moquitto line in a script and just execute the script.